# c# regex get html tag content

Tags: c#, regex

This is my html :

```
<div class="bla">
    <div>
        bla bla
    </div>
    <div>
        bla bla 2
    </div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

I want to get `class="bla"` content with c# regex. I've tryied :

```
MatchCollection postCollection = Regex.Matches(html, "<div class=\"bla\".*?>(.*?)<\\/div>");
```

But it only gives me this portion of content:

```
<div class="bla">
    <div>
        bla bla
    </div>
```

As soon as first div closes.

Comment: You should really use a HTML parser like Html Agility Pack for dealing with HTML, rather than regexes. [Here is the classic answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) explaining why.

Comment: Why not use a DOM parser instead?

Comment: well i am parsing facebook, and these tags are inside code hidden tag. html agility pack cant see it

Comment: After html load,it dinamicly creates html from javascript

Comment: @user3857731: `"html agility pack cant see it"` - If your code can't even *see* the markup, then how do you expect a regular expression to work either?  It really sounds like you're inventing a problem that was solved long ago.  If you have HTML to parse, use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 2):

Use a DOM parser, regex is not suitable for this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack

But as you mention that the page is generated at runtime with JavaScript this is not a suitable option.
You will need a browser-like component: for example Selenium

Here you can find some examples: http://scraping.pro/example-of-scraping-with-selenium-webdriver-in-csharp/

Comment: I am using cron job for this purpose and is it suitable to use navigator?

Comment: Also i am sendig cookies, make automatic log in on facebook, if i just browse the page it won't help

Comment: Cookies is not a problem, the API allows to add cookies. I'm worried about your questions. Cron job is linux only, and navigator is a discontinued browser since 2008.

Comment: Good luck with Regex, see you again when Facebook changes a small thing in the HTML and your regex doesn't work again.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you shouldn't use Regex for such cases. However, it is possible.

Here is my attempt at doing so:
`(<div class="bla".*>([\w\s<>\/]*)<\/div>)`

This surely needs more work and may be buggy, but could possibly head you in right direction.

Regex demo: [here](https://regex101.com/r/vG0lU7/1)

Comment: This still has problems if you add more divs after it, though. And since you can't tell regex to stop after given number of `</div>` has occured, this might be quite tricky.